# apex_item into a specific subregion

Tags: oracle-apex

Hi I need to create programmatically some items, but I need them to be located into a specific subregion, from [apex_item](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) documentation I cannot see how this could be achieved, is this possible?

For instance a text item parameters are:

```
APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
    p_idx         IN    NUMBER,
    p_value       IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_size        IN    NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
    p_maxlength   IN    NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
    p_attributes  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_item_id     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_item_label  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

But none of them indicates where to put it.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic items must be generated in a report or dynamic PL/SQL region, so create the subregion using one of these region types.